# How to set application version for Symfony WebProfiler?

Tags: php, symfony, profiler

according to [this commit](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/d35cb9f8801bc7984fe28cadbaf1cebabd7b1d63) you can set your own application name and version for the WebProfiler. Now I'm asking myself (and you ^^) what's the intended way to do this?

```
/**
 * Constructor.
 *
 * @param string $name The name of the application using the web profiler
 * @param string $version The version of the application using the web profiler
 */
 public function __construct($name = null, $version = null)
 {
     $this->name = $name;
     $this->version = $version;
 }
```

The collector is defined in [ConfigDataCollector](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/d35cb9f8801bc7984fe28cadbaf1cebabd7b1d63/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DataCollector/ConfigDataCollector.php) of the `HttpKernel` component and its constructor has two parameters defaulting to `null`. The service is configured in the [collectors.xml](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/d35cb9f8801bc7984fe28cadbaf1cebabd7b1d63/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/collectors.xml) of the `FrameWorkBundle`, but there's no way to set the parameters.

I've now overriden collector class by setting the `data_collector.config.class` in `app/config/config.yml` and injecting my application's version this way... but this totally feels wrong.

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

The [commit](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/d35cb9f8801bc7984fe28cadbaf1cebabd7b1d63) message says (emphasis mine):

> [WebProfiler] added the possibility to **override** the application name/version in the WDT

I *presume* that the way to do it would be the way you did it, that is, use your own class that extends `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\ConfigDataCollector` and override the constructor to set the properties (`name` and `version`).

If someone knows a better way to do it, it'd be appreciated!

Comment: Yeah... it's confusing. It also just could mean that this "overrides" the default "sf 2.x.x" in the toolbar with "acme 1.2.3". Overriding the collector just doesn't feel really Symfony-way like. :/